# What's the reason behind having an additional atara on the middle of the talis gadol?

Tags: minhag, tallit-gadol

Here an example of the Belz Rebbe talis with an additional atara in the middle
Any sources on this custom ?

[image: Belz Rebbe talis]

Comment: It started off as an easy way to solve the Tallis from splitting in half. If you fold it in the folds vigorously every day, it tends to fray and then you get 2 halves. From there to adding an Atara to the strip was a "logical" leap.

Comment: I always assumed it was related to the gartel and dividing top from bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an attempt to mitigate the issue of giving undue importance to the part of the cloth that covers the head. There is an old argument if one needs to be careful to always have the taalis on the same direction. Origionaly, a cloth was sewn on the inside to mark which way is up. Eventually it made it's way to the outside, even becoming silver. This presented an interesting problem as now it seems that main point of the taalis is an atifa for the head, which is not how we rule. We rule that the main atifa is on the body. An attemt to limit this perception was to sew a piece down the middle of the taalis. See the Aruch Hashulchan in siman 8 siff 10 where he discusses this approach as pertains to a silver atara and strip.

Comment: The original tallis design, with no atara and a lining, is preserved in today's Chabad talleisim. The Belz tallis has both a lining and a plain satin atara with no design at all. http://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/chassidic-tallis/ My assumption is that they, too, are trying to avoid having the atara steal the limelight from the tallis and tzitzis. I wrote about the atara issue here. http://www.tallit-shop.com/chabad-tallis-why-no-atara/